Custumize Ubuntu for 1920x1080 200% = 960x540
(Novice here. I did some search but has not been succesful.)
Screen size is 1920x1080. I am happy with 200%. The resulting size is 960x540. But GNOME doesn't work. App center doesn't fit in. What to do?
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-09-11 16:20:21

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Acer Swift SF114-34
Memory:                                      4.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Pentium® Silver N6000 × 4
Graphics:                                    Intel® UHD Graphics (JSL)
Disk Capacity:                               128.0 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            V1.16
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-44-generic


Your hardware config is a bit lite for Ubuntu 24.04

Unfortunately, minimum Ubuntu Installation and System Requirements specify that you need

1024x768 or higher resolution display.

Please, refer to this documentation.
You can use Fractional Scaling (with a scale of 125 or maybe 150 %) on Display of gnome-control-center.
